# Media buttons on keyboard with spotify

Tags: keyboard, media, button, spotify

I've added spotify preview as my defualt music program, by doing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95345/how-to-make-spotify-the-default-music-player).

> As doug suggested, simply add this line to your >~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list file in two places, like so:
>
> [Default Applications]
>   ...
>   audio/x-vorbis+ogg=spotify.desktop
>
> [Added Associations]
>   ...
>   audio/x-vorbis+ogg=spotify.desktop;

But the media buttons doesnt seem to wanna work. Is there any easy known way to fix this without binding special keys etc perhaps?

Comment: Which computer are you using? Is it a laptop or a desktop? If it's a laptop please provide the model, if it's a desktop, please provide the keyboard model/

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `defualt` to `default`, `doesnt` to `doesn't`, and `wanna` to `want to` so that English translating software can work properly.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with the Spotify Linux client. It's something that the company is aware of, but in the meantime you can use the [Spotify Gnome Integration](http://www.noswap.com/projects/spotify-gnome/) software to get the media keys working.

**Edit**: Hooray, we added this feature in client version 0.9.4! It should now work, if it doesn't then please post a message on the community forums.

Comment: Worked fantastically in quantal as well, latest build still doesn't appear to support the media keys.

Comment: It seems that the media keys work if the client is in the focused, but not when you're in an other program, which is annoying

Comment: @edi9999 this is not the case for me. which window manager are you using?

Comment: I'm using spotify v0.9.10 and the X window manager. It works now thanks to the dbus command with custom keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard's media keys (means the "XF86Audio*" keys, usually <kbd>Fn</kbd> + Arrows) work in Spotify out of the box now – but depending on your desktop environment and configuration, maybe only if Spotify has the keyboard focus. Sometimes, a solution is to make Spotify the default music application, but there are alternatives:

**Solution for Lubuntu / LXDE / OpenBox**

The following configures the media keys as global keyboard shortcuts that always control Spotify:

1. Install the [Spotify command line client `sp`](https://gist.github.com/duncan-bayne/3f7ef98a15b02b693bf47a03fda79b3a), a small bash script controlling Spotify via DBUS: just save the `sp` file as `/usr/local/bin/sp` and make it executable.
2. Open `~/.config/opebox/lubuntu-rc.xml` and somewhere between `<keyboard>…</keyboard>`, add:

   ```
   <keybind key="XF86AudioPlay">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>sp play</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="XF86AudioStop">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>sp pause</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="XF86AudioNext">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>sp next</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="XF86AudioPrev">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>sp prev</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   ```
3. Save the file and make your changes effective by executing:

   ```
   openbox --reconfigure
   ```

**Sources:**

- [sp Spotify command line client](https://gist.github.com/duncan-bayne/3f7ef98a15b02b693bf47a03fda79b3a), in the improved version by duncan-bayne
- [LXDE wiki on changing keyboard shortcuts](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#Change_hotkeys)
- [Config snippet](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#What_about_the_Play.2C_Stop.2C_Previous_and_Next_buttons.3F) from the LXDE wiki for global media key shortcuts